# Can I server the Rancher Server through a hosted Traefik container?

Tags: docker, rancher, traefik

I have a single dedicated server where I have installed a Rancher server and a Rancher client and is used to host some dockerized services.

I have succesfully installed Traefik and it is configured with the Rancher API backend, and it reverse proxies my services, hosting them behind HTTPS and everything is working fine.

But I still access my Rancher server through htttp://12.34.56.78:8080.  I would like to also put the Rancher server behind Traefik with https enabled too.

I tried starting the Rancher server with:

```
sudo docker run -d \
  -v /data/rancher/server/data:/var/lib/mysql \
  --restart=unless-stopped \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -l traefik.frontend.rule=Host:rancher.mydomainname.com \
  -l traefik.enable=true \
  -l traefik.backend=rancher \
  -l traefik.default.protocol=http \
  -l traefik.port=8080 \
  rancher/server:v1.6.12
```

(the same way I configured all my other services) but it is not picked up by Traefik because (I think) the Rancher Server does NOT appear in the Rancher API requests that Traefik is monitoring (since Rancher server is started outside Rancher and not hosted by it).

Coming from [Rancher Active Proxy](https://github.com/adi90x/rancher-active-proxy), this is something that [it was supported](https://github.com/adi90x/rancher-active-proxy#special-attention-for-standalone-containers) by that tool

If my reasoning is correct, that Traefik cannot "pick up" the Rancher server that way, an alternative solution I was thinking was that maybe I would have to create a separate `[file]` section solely for the Rancher server and add it to the Traefik .toml file...

Is this the correct approach to achieve what I want, or is there some better way of doing this...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost 2 years late to the party, but I just started `rancher` with `traefik` with a `[docker]` backend.

The docker-compose file for rancher:

```
version: '3'

services:

  web:
   image: rancher/rancher:latest
   labels:
     traefik.enable: true
     traefik.backend: rancher
     traefik.frontend.entryPoints: http,https
     traefik.frontend.passHostHeader: true
     traefik.frontend.rule: "Host:rancher.mydomain.com"
     traefik.backend.port: 80
     traefik.port: 80
   restart: unless-stopped
```

Maybe it's useful for anyone stumbling on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Partially, answering my question...

Creating a separate static `rancherserver.toml` file:

```
[backends]
[backends.rancherserver]
    [backends.rancherserver.servers.server1]
    url = "http://12.34.56.78:8080"
    weight = 10

[frontends]
[frontends.rancherserver]
backend = "rancherserver"
passHostHeader = true
entrypoints = ["https"] 
    [frontends.rancherserver.routes.onlyone]
    rule = "Host:rancher.mydomain.com"
```

(where 12.34.56.78 is the real physical IP address ofthe physical server) seems that solves my problem, able to access the Rancher server at htttps://rancher.mydomain.com (with automatic forward from http to https)

**BUT** for some reason, I'm still able to access the Rancher server from htttp://12.34.56.78:8080 (note, this is not https) although the physical server has firewalled **all** ports (ufw on Ubuntu) except 80 and 433 (and some others):

```
me@server:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
[sudo] password for me: 
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
1143                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
1110                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
Anywhere on docker0        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
1143 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
1110 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
Anywhere (v6) on docker0   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

So, I still think I'm misusing Traefik somewhow and allowing the 8080 port to leak trough my Traefik configuration... :(

Comment: I know this is an old question but leaving a comment just for the record: you are able to access rancher through  htttp://12.34.56.78:8080 because you have published the port in the `docker run` command. Docker circumvents firewalls and enables publishing of all manually published ports. If you use `traefik` you don't need to publish ports. Trafik uses docker's internal network to route traffic.

Comment: i don't see port `8080` denied in above configuration. docker doesn't "circumvent firewalls". It may create new networks, but any traffic still has to pass your host interface (with the firewall).